# Older than I am, me, I, he

Tags: word-choice, british-english

Which of these is the preferred choice in BrE?

1. He is older than I/she/we/he/they.
2. He is older than I am/she/he is/they are.

3.He is older than me/her/him/them.

Comment: Have you tried using Google Ngrams? _Older than I [am]_ is the officially 'correct' version, but you will hear many people say _older than me_ in everyday speech.

Comment: @Kate Bunting , Some native speakers on this forum said  they are not exact.

Comment: And hardly anyone would respond to the question: **Who's there?** by saying: **It is I.**  unless they wanted some funny looks. The response **It's me** is universal. On the other hand, the wretched **from/with/to my wife/husband/ and I** has gone in the other direction.

Comment: They are all possible. In cases where the the pronoun is understood as object or complement of a preposition like "than", it as accusative, as in unreduced clauses: _He is older than **me**_. But if it is understood as subject, the choice of case depends on the style. In formal style it appears as nominative, again as in unreduced clauses: _He is older than **I** am_, but informal style has accusative "me", as in _He is older than **me**_, where the missing verb cannot be inserted.